# Order statistic

Tags: order-statistics

The random variables $X_1, X_2, \ldots , X_n, Y_1, Y_2, \ldots , Y_n$ are independent
and $U(0, a)$-distributed. How to determine the distribution of
$$Z_n = n\log\frac {\max\{X_{(n)}, Y_{(n)}\}} {\min\{X_{(n)}, Y_{(n)}\}}$$

Comment: Does $Z_n$ depend on all the $X_i$s and $Y_i$s or just on $X_n$ and $Y_n$?

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, this can be written as
$$
Z_n = |A_n - B_n|,
$$
where $A_n = n \log X_{(n)}$, $B_n = n\log Y_{(n)}$. Notice that $A_n$ and $B_n$ are iid, so in particular $A_n - B_n$ has a symmetric distribution. Thus, the solution can be done in such steps:

1. Identify the distribution of $A_n$.
2. Using the convolution formula or otherwise identify the pdf $f_n$ of $A_n - B_n$.
3. Using the symmetry, the pdf of $Z_n$ is $g_n(x) = 2 f_n(x) \mathbf{1}_{[0,+\infty)}(x)$.

Comment: Should it not be $A_n=n\cdot log(max(X_{(n)},Y_{(n)}))$ and $B_n=n\cdot log(min(X_{(n)},Y_{(n)}))$?

Comment: No, it shouldn't (the absolute value takes care of that).